# How to remove records in store when they are not in server anymore

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have application which may lost connection with server for days and when it finally reconnect some record exist in store didn’t exist in server any more. 
I need to remove these records without create flickering in the ui.

I try to fix it but can’t get any where.

store.findall didn’t seems to have option to delete record not returned by server.

I can’t find ways to chain store.unloadAll and store.findAll without have the blank state take effect on the screen and cause flickering

I also can’t find out how to get what actually returned by server without go completely manual (make my own ajax calls,which won’t scale obviously)

I am wondering what everyone else is using in this situation

Thanks for any help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/mcve) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the ***shouldBackgroundReloadAll*** and ***shouldBackgroundReloadRecord*** implementation on your adapter.

As stated at ember adapter documentation:

> This method is used by the store to determine if the store should
>   reload a record array after the store.findAll method resolves with a
>   cached record array.

Something like:

```
// app/adapters/application.js

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({

  shouldReloadRecord: function(store, snapshot) {
    return true;
  },

  shouldReloadAll: function(store, snapshot) {
    return true;
  },

  // If this method returns true the store will re-fetch a record from the adapter.
  shouldBackgroundReloadRecord: function(store, snapshot) {
    return true;
  },

  // If this method returns true the store will re-fetch all records from the adapter.
  shouldBackgroundReloadAll: function(store, snapshot) {
    return true;
  }

});
```

Reference: https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.15/classes/DS.Adapter/methods/shouldBackgroundReloadAll?anchor=shouldBackgroundReloadAll

Comment: It won't work. It has no different from passing { reload: true } to findall,

Answer (score 0):

You could get all records in store via [`peekRecord()`](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.0/classes/DS.Store/methods/peekRecord?anchor=peekRecord) and then [`reload()`](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.0/classes/DS.Model/methods/reload?anchor=reload) each record. If your UI is not depending on [`isReloading`](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.0/classes/DS.Model/properties/isReloading?anchor=isReloading) property of model, reloading should not change view until finished. If your API supports [`coalesceFindRequests`](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.0/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter/properties/coalesceFindRequests?anchor=coalesceFindRequests) and you make sure to execute the reload for all records of a model in same runloop, this should only trigger one request.

Disclaimer: I did not tested this approach but it should work. Let me know, if you face any issues.